# Xtext: Create a project wizard for the DSL without src, src-gen etc

Tags: dsl, wizard, xtext

I ran across some information about creating a new project wizard for my dsl language, and succeeded creating such wizard by adding

```
    fragment = ui.projectWizard.SimpleProjectWizardFragment2 {
        generate = true
    }
```

to my workflow.

However, when using the wizard it also creates unnecessary files and folders such as `build.properties`, `META-INF`, `src`, `src-gen`, `JRE System Library`.
Basically I just want an **empty project** associated with my DSL.

I succeeded removing `META-INF` and `build.properties` by calling

```
try {
    project.getFile("build.properties").delete(true, null);
    project.getFolder("META-INF").delete(true, null);
    } catch (CoreException e) {}
```

from the end of `enhanceProject(..)` in my customized `DSLProjectCreator2` (that extends `DSLProjectCreator`).

But if I'm using this way for deleting `src` and `src-gen` I get an error marker says that `src` and `src-gen` are missing (however this won't solve removing `JRE System Library`).

How can I solve this?

Comment: Which version of xtext do you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahhh you way of enabling the wizard is a bit odd

```
newProjectWizardForEclipse = {
    pluginProject = false
    generate = true
}
```

what about not creating the folders instead of deleting them.

```
class MyDslNewProjectWizardInitialContents {
    @Inject
    FileExtensionProvider fileExtensionProvider

    def generateInitialContents(IFileSystemAccess2 fsa) {
        fsa.generateFile(
            "Model." + fileExtensionProvider.primaryFileExtension,
            '''
            /*
             * This is an example model
             */
            Hello Xtext!
            '''
            )
    }
}

public class MyDslProjectCreatorCustom extends MyDslProjectCreator {

    @Override
    protected List<String> getAllFolders() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

}
```

i dont know why you get a java project created. do you use xbase? which Project Factory is bound?

how does the generated MyDslProjectCreator look like?
does it use JavaProjectFactory or PluginProjectFactory

Comment: Using `pluginProject = false` and `protected List<String> getAllFolders() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }` absolutely solved my problem. Thanks!